# Finish all activities and keep appearing in recent applications

Tags: android, android-activity

I have used `finishAffinity` or `below code` because of finish all activities. But my application removed recent applications.

I want to finish all activities and keep appearing in recent applications. How can I do that?

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. **How about:** `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag? `Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Thank you. Will it be solved if I use it? Will I remove System.exit

Comment: You won't need these: `finish();
            System.exit(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is used to remove a number of Activitys belonging to a specific
>   application from the current task (which may contain Activitys
>   belonging to multiple applications)

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Happy coding :) Glad to help.